# Выполняются ли sql запросы если кешировать html

Tags: mysql, кэширование

Выполняются ли sql запросы когда кеширован HTML

Comment: Какое поведение вы написали в коде при реализации кэширования, то выполняться и будет

Comment: ну например если кеширование разрешено в самом HTML